# прописать location к конкретной папке в nginx

Tags: nginx

Мне нужно в файле nginx.conf прописать в:

```
server {
...
    location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css)$ {
        expires max;
    }
...
}
```

Настройки кеша. Могу я прописать location к конкретной папке и как это должно выглядеть?

Путь для примера такой /var/www/mysite.ru/data/www/mysite.ru/content/files/images/logo.png

Comment: Можешь, конечно.

Comment: Окей, а можно код для примера как это должно выглядеть?